# Mean of a large matrix of 40x455 (data from 5 sessions i.e 40x91 each sessions)

Tags: matlab, matrix, mean

I have a large matrix of 40x455 (data from 5 sessions i.e 40x91 each session). I  would like to take the mean of each element in the form of 40x91 in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand:

```
M = randi([1, 100], 40, 455);
a1 = blockproc(M,[1,91],@(x)mean2(x.data));
```

Comment: Thanks. it was helpful. The mean was from each element from the 40x91 matrix and displayed in the 40x5 matrix. I was wondering if we can have mean in 40x91 instead of 40x5.

Comment: Thanks. it was helpful. The mean was from each element from the 40x91 matrix out of the large matrix and displayed in the 40x5 matrix. I was wondering if we can have mean in 40x91 instead of 40x5.

Comment: a1 = blockproc(M,[1,5],@(x)mean2(x.data));

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this does not gives me a correct mean. Probably, my question was confusing. I will try to explain other way. The large matrix 40x455 is horzcat of original 5 matrix (40x91). So, I would like to take the mean of each 5 matrix in 40x91format.